# JSON GET AND POST in Python

Tags: python, json, ssl, post, get

I'm currently working on automazing dating applications, espcially a french app called Fruitz.

I've reverse engineering the api, in order to get me POST,GET sequences.

I'm trying this kind of function :

```
def set_location(location_user):
try:
    u= '....appspot.com:443/.../location'
    d= requests.post(u, headers=headers, timeout=0.7,data=location_user)
    gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
except KeyError:
    raise
```

with those headers :

```
headers = {
'User-Agent':'okhttp/3.6.0',
'Host':'....appspot.com:443',
'connection' : 'Keep-Alive',
'Content-type' : 'application/json',
'x-...-uuid': '...',
'x-...-token': '...'
```

I'm currently getting this problem :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\DEV\OPU\DEV\fruitz.py", line 696, in set_location
d= requests.post(u, headers=headers, timeout=0.7,data=location_user)
  File "c:\users\jules\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jules\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jules\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jules\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jules\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 506, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='....appspot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: .../location (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Any ideas ?

Jules

Comment: You don't have a cert for your app site so you can't use https

Comment: So i need to use HTTP in instance ?

Comment: Any ideas about implementing certifcates for HTtPS in python ?

Answer (score 1):

Fix certificates as suggested by mVChr or add verify=False to requests.post (you can also pass the certificate to verify http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)